# Android onListItemClick after disconecting udb does not work

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

story:
I have todo list app with 2 fragments. 
In landscape I can see both fragments (list and details).
When i push on list item display fragments is showing its details.
This works when phone is connected with usb to pc or in wifi debbuging.

Problem starts when disconnecting phone from usb.
When I run app on phone, onListItemClick method is not switching details fragment. 
How can I see where is the problem if I can not debug it?

Here is that method:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);        
    TodoItem todoItem = (TodoItem) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);       
    showDetails(todoItem.getId());
}
```

P.S. Portrait mode working fine.

Maybe You guys have some ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found out that problem was in bundle, it was not initialized correctly.